# tkinter: how to get the result from a button and use it in a function?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, button, tkinter

I want the user to click a button called "choose a folder" and it allows them to choose a folder from their directory and then click a button called "choose csv" and it allows them to choose a csv. Then I want the user to click price difference, where it will get those folder paths and find a price difference within the file.

I created functions to get the folder path and csv, but I am having trouble returning the results from the user to `avgprice()`.

Here is the code I have so far:

```
import tkinter as tk
global folder_path
import tkinter.ttk
from tkinter import filedialog
from tkinter import *
import pandas as pd
from tkinter.filedialog import askopenfilename
LARGE_FONT= ("Verdana", 12)


class SeaofBTCapp(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        container = tk.Frame(self)
        container.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand = True)
        container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

        self.frames = {}
        frame = StartPage(container, self)
        self.frames[StartPage] = frame
        frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")
        self.show_frame(StartPage)

    def show_frame(self, cont):
        frame = self.frames[cont]
        frame.tkraise()


class StartPage(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
            tk.Frame.__init__(self,parent)
            label = tk.Label(self, text="BTC Price Difference", font=LARGE_FONT)
            label.pack(pady=10,padx=10)
            first_window_button = tk.Button(self, text="select Folder", command= self.browse_button)
            first_window_button.pack()
            first_window_csv_button = tk.Button(self, text="select csv", command= self.import_csv_data)
            first_window_csv_button.pack()
            first_window_diffbutton = tk.Button(self, text="Price difference", command= self.avgprice)
            first_window_diffbutton.pack()
            closebutton=tk.Button(self,text="Quit",command=controller.destroy)
            closebutton.pack()

    def browse_button(self):
        # Allow user to select a directory and store it in global var
        #called folder_path
        folder_path = StringVar()
        filename = filedialog.askdirectory()
        folder_path.set(filename)
        return filename

    def import_csv_data(self):
        csv_file_path = askopenfilename()
        df = pd.read_csv(csv_file_path)
        return df

    def avgprice(self):
        path1=self.browse_button()
        path2=self.import_csv_data()
```

I am running into an issue in `avgprice()` as I do not want the window to select file show up again, I just want the entries to save from what the user chose when clicking all the buttons. Is there a way to use `.get()` here?

Comment: I see a few things here. 1: you are using global in a class. Use a class attribute instead. 2: `self.askopenfilename` is wrong it is just `askopenfilename`. `self.` will make the program look for a class attribute called `self.askopenfilename` and that does not exist so that will error out. 3: you have `v.set()` but do not define `v` so that will error as well. This again should be a class attribute. 4: `pd` is not defined. I am assuming this is from pandas or some other library that can read csv but you do not show this in your imports. 5: `path2=self.import_csv_data` does nothing.

Comment: I edited 1, 3,4, and 5, unsure what you mean by 2?

Comment: For 2 you had written the line of code `csv_file_path = self.askopenfilename()`. This tells me that you do not know what `self.` is for. That or you made a mistake by putting it there. The prefix `self.` is what defines a class attribute. A class attribute is either a function or variable that has been defined as a class attribute or method with the use of self. What this allows is for the class to be able to access those variables/functions from anywhere in the class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see a few things here.

1. you are using global in a class. Use a class attribute instead.
2. `self.askopenfilename` is wrong it is just `askopenfilename`. self. will make the program look for a class attribute called `self.askopenfilename` and that does not exist so that will error out.
3. you have `v.set()` but do not define v so that will error as well. This again should be a class attribute.
4. pd is not defined. I am assuming this is from pandas or some other library that can read csv but you do not show this in your imports.
5. `path2=self.import_csv_data` does nothing.
6. You use `global folder_path` in the global namespace. `global` is not used this way and in this case is does nothing of use. `global` is used inside of a function to tell that function that a variable exist outside of the function in the global namespace so using it in the global name space is pointless.
7. You are already doing `import tkinter as tk` you do not also need to do `from tkinter import *`. The `*` method can cause you to overwrite methods if you are not careful so the preferred method for importing tkinter is to use `import tkinter as tk` and simply use the `tk.` prefix for everything.

Cleaned up example. Let me know if you have any questions:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import filedialog
from tkinter.filedialog import askopenfilename

LARGE_FONT = ("Verdana", 12)


class SeaofBTCapp(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        container = tk.Frame(self)
        container.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='ew')
        container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.frames = {}
        frame = StartPage()
        self.frames[StartPage] = frame
        frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")
        self.show_frame(StartPage)

    def show_frame(self, cont):
        frame = self.frames[cont]
        frame.tkraise()


class StartPage(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.v = ''
        self.file_path = ''
        self.folder_path = ''

        tk.Label(self, text="BTC Price Difference", font=LARGE_FONT).pack(pady=10, padx=10)
        tk.Button(self, text="select Folder", command=self.browse_button).pack()
        tk.Button(self, text="select csv", command=self.import_csv_data).pack()
        tk.Button(self, text="Price difference", command=self.avgprice).pack()
        tk.Button(self, text="Quit", command=self.master.destroy).pack()

    def browse_button(self):
        filename = filedialog.askdirectory()
        print(filename)
        self.folder_path = filename

    def import_csv_data(self):
        csv_file_path = askopenfilename()
        print(csv_file_path)
        self.file_path = csv_file_path
        # df = pd.read_csv(csv_file_path)

    def avgprice(self):
        path1 = self.folder_path
        path2 = self.file_path
        print('folder_path: ', path1)
        print('file_path: ', path2)


SeaofBTCapp().mainloop()
```